# How to echo $username variable into a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there is a way to display or echo a `$username` variable within a javascript function that display an html string. This is the original function:

```
    Plugin.prototype.counter = function() {
    if (this.s.counter) {
    $(this.s.appendCounterTo).append('<div id="counter"><span id="counter-current">' 
        + (parseInt(this.index, 10) + 1) + '</span> / <span id="counter-all">' 
        + this.$items.length 
        + '</span><a href="index.htm"><sig> JOHN SMITH </sig><img src="jOHN.png"></a></div>');
    }
};
```

I've tried inserting this:

```
    <?php $arrays = file_get_contents('username.txt'); echo $arrays;?>
```

Instead of `JOHN SMITH`, with and without quotes... Not working.

Any idea how to do such task?

Comment: Rather than `not working` what happens? Is this a `.php` file?

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? There's a `>` missing from your php code, at the end.

Comment: @aron9forever looks like this was just a bad edit job by me; fixed now...

Comment: Well then the PHP code itself is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess here, it's possible your file is being called incorrectly.

This will specify the absolute path on the server.

```
<?=file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/username.txt');?>
```